# iOS: Get top of keyboard point in iPad modal view?

Tags: ios, ipad, frame, modalviewcontroller, uikeyboard

I need to adjust a 'message bar' when the keyboard is shown and am having issues when using iPad modal view controller. The 'message bar' should sit right on top of the keyboard when it is shown, and then at the bottom of the modal when the keyboard is hidden (a la Messages app style).

The problem is I need to get the top most point of the keyboard's frame in terms of the Modal's coordinate system.
I found this answer that theoretically seems correct, but doesn't work ([How can I find portion of my view which isn't covered by the keyboard (UIModalPresenationStyleFormSheet)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806282/how-can-i-find-portion-of-my-view-which-isnt-covered-by-the-keyboard-uimodalpr)):

**FYI When the keyboard is shown, the keyboard's frame in the main window (i.e. 'keyboardFrame') = (-84.0, 526.0, 768.0, 264.0). The keyboard's frame when translated for the modal view controller coordinate system (i.e. 'newSize') = (-168.0, 292.0, 768.0, 264.0)***

```
// Convert the keyboard rect into the view controller's coordinate system
// The fromView: nil means keyboardRect is in the main window's coordinate system
let newSize = self.view.convertRect(keyboardFrame, fromView: nil)

// And then this is the part that gets covered!
let keyboardCoveredHeight = self.view.bounds.height - newSize.origin.y
self.messageToolbar.bottomConstraint.constant = -keyboardCoveredHeight
```

[image]

Comment: [This is what you need to read](http://www.think-in-g.net/ghawk/blog/2012/09/practicing-auto-layout-an-example-of-keyboard-sensitive-layout/)

Comment: @Lefteris - I did use that as a guide. As stated in the OP, the problem is when using a Modal View Controller in iPad. The keyboards frame is relative to the main window, not the modal. So in order to set the bottom constraint to the correct value, I need to know what point (in terms of the modal's coordinate system) the top of the keyboard is located. But the current method to do so does not give the accurate translated value.

Comment: That doc says "the keyboard’s frame we get in the callback is always represented in the portrait orientation", which is no longer true in iOS 8. In iOS 8, rotations are handled simply as size changes, so the device's orientation doesn't need to be accounted for.

Comment: @AaronBrager That's true, but again, not the issue at hand. Again, the problem is getting the "correct coordinate" in regards to the Modal View Controller's Coordinate system where the top of the keyboard lies (displayed in the main window's coordinate system)

Comment: Why don't you put your messageToolbar as the inputAccessoryView ? it will be align to top of keyboard.

Comment: @netbe I don't think the OP wants it to take up the full width of the screen.

Comment: Did you try using convert rect methods which convert a view frame from one view to another. You could convert your controllers view frame to the main window coordinate system and use that to compute the size of the box.

Comment: @netbe - Yes, we wanted the toolbar to be shown even when keyboard is not active.

Comment: @MaticOblak That is exactly what I did (see code above). The problem was that the returned frame was still innaccurate. It kept returning '292' as the Y origin, which was clearly not correct as the modal view was 600pts height and the keyboard only covered roughly 60pts of the bottom of the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a familiar category to get the proper keyboard frame in a iPad modal view:

```
- (CGFloat)heightCoveredByKeyboardOfSize:(CGSize)keyboardSize
{
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
CGRect frameInWindow = [self convertRect:self.bounds toView:nil];
CGRect windowBounds = self.window.bounds;

CGFloat keyboardTop;
CGFloat heightCoveredByKeyboard;

//Determine height of the view covered by the keyboard relative to current rotation

switch (orientation)
{
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        keyboardTop = windowBounds.size.height - keyboardSize.height;
        heightCoveredByKeyboard = windowBounds.size.height - frameInWindow.origin.y - keyboardTop;
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
    default:
        keyboardTop = windowBounds.size.height - keyboardSize.height;
        heightCoveredByKeyboard = CGRectGetMaxY(frameInWindow) - keyboardTop;
        break;
}

return MAX(0.0f,heightCoveredByKeyboard);
}
```

along with DAKeyboardControl (for panning):

```
    // Use [unowned self] in closure for weak reference
    self.view.addKeyboardPanningWithFrameBasedActionHandler(nil, constraintBasedActionHandler: { [unowned self] (keyboardFrameInView, opening, closing) -> Void in
        if opening
        {
            if UIDevice.isIpad()
            {
                // iPad requires a different method due to use of modal view
                self.messageToolbar.bottomConstraint.constant = -self.view.heightCoveredByKeyboardOfSize(keyboardFrameInView.size)
            }
            else
            {
                self.messageToolbar.bottomConstraint.constant = -keyboardFrameInView.size.height
            }
        }

        if closing
        {
            self.messageToolbar.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
        }

        self.view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to calculate exact overlap this way, on keyboardDidShowNotification

```
let parentRelativeFrame = view.convert(view.frame, to: nil)
let viewBottomVerticalOffset = parentRelativeFrame.origin.y + parentRelativeFrame.height
let overlap = viewBottomVerticalOffset - keyboardFrame.origin.y
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into one of two problems (maybe both):

1. In iOS 8, you have to convert the keyboard's rect from the screen's coordinate space
2. On iPad, the sheet views sometimes move up a bit when the keyboard is displayed, which happens *after* the keyboard is shown, so you need to calculate the results *again* in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

Here's [a sample project that does what you want](http://cl.ly/3S3E1t2m3h0y?_ga=1.232433567.1647436446.1424986464).

For posterity, here's the interesting source code:

```
class TypingViewController: UIViewController {

    var keyboardHoverView: UIView! // your keyboard toolbar or whatever
    var lastKeyboardFrame : CGRect! // whenever you get a frame update, store it here

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createKeyboardHoverView()
        observeKeyboard()
    }

    func createKeyboardHoverView() {
        // make your keyboard toolbar
        keyboardHoverView = view
    }

    func observeKeyboard() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification : NSNotification) {
        let dict = notification.userInfo!
        let frameValue = dict[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
        lastKeyboardFrame = frameValue.CGRectValue()

        moveKeyboardView()
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification : NSNotification) {
        moveKeyboardView()
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        // this moves the view again, in case the modal view has shifted up
        moveKeyboardView()
    }

    func moveKeyboardView() {
        if lastKeyboardFrame != nil {
            // this conversion is used in iOS 8 and differs from most online tutorials
            let frameInThisView = self.view.convertRect(lastKeyboardFrame, fromCoordinateSpace: view.window!.screen.coordinateSpace)

            var newRect = keyboardHoverView.frame
            newRect.origin.y = frameInThisView.origin.y - CGRectGetHeight(newRect)
            keyboardHoverView.frame = newRect

            println("Setting rect: \(newRect)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (Note that I didn't fully implement `keyboardWillHide()`, but you should be able to get the gist from this.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info @Aaron! I am still getting the same frame size for the keyboard when I try to convert using your updated 'fromCoordinate' version: (-168.0, 292.0, 768.0, 264.0). The '292' Y origin is just way off. The modal view is 600 and the keyboard covers roughly 60 points from the bottom (using the message bar's 44pt height as a guide). Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Frustrated.

Comment: @JamesHickman Can you upload a sample project that reproduces the behavior? Also, are you using the same notification? (`UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`)? Finally, what happens if you use the view controller from my sample project in your app?